# running Build.PL Could not create MYMETA files

Tags: perl

I want to install File-MimeInfo-0.16 package and run "perl Build.PL", it threw out:

```
Could not create MYMETA files
Creating new 'Build' script for 'File-MimeInfo' version '0.16'
```

Does anyone know how to fix? thanks in advance

Comment: You want to get that second line. As for the first, are you sure it's a problem? Do you have permissions to write in the current work directory?

Answer (score 0):

The package that creates MYMETA.json and MYMETA.yml files is called `CPAN::Meta`. You can install it with one of the following:

- Mac OS X: type `sudo port install p5-cpan-meta` in the terminal (assuming you have [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) installed)
- Ubuntu Linux: type `sudo apt-get install libcpan-meta-perl` in the terminal
- Other platforms: run the CPAN shell (typically by typing `cpan` from a terminal or command prompt), and type:

  `install CPAN::Meta`

Answer (score -1):

You can install [File::MimeInfo](http://search.cpan.org/~pardus/File-MimeInfo-0.16/lib/File/MimeInfo.pm) from CPAN directly.

```
cpan File::MineInfo
```

OR, if you want to do it manually,

1. Install the following dependencies if you don't have them:

   - Carp
   - Exporter
   - Fcntl
   - Pod::Usage
   - File::Basename
   - File::BaseDir
   - File::DesktopEntry
2. Download the distribution

   ```
   wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PA/PARDUS/File-MimeInfo/File-MimeInfo-0.16.tar.gz
   ```
3. Run the following sequence of command:

   ```
   tar xvzf File-MimeInfo-0.16.tar.gz
   cd File-MimeInfo-0.16
   perl MakeFile.PL
   make test
   make install
   ```

I do not know why you want to run `perl Build.PL`.

But as far as installation of the module is concerned, above step will get you the module installed for sure (Provided you take care of the dependencies...OR use CPAN)

**PS:** Above instruction are meant for Linux platform. I have never done any perlish thing on windows.

Comment: Re "I do not know why you want to run `perl Build.PL`", Do you know a reason he wouldn't want to? After all, `perl MakeFile.PL` will just end up doing the same thing. I don't see that helping in the least.